# Openshift: How to alert/publish a message if deployment/build fails

Tags: openshift

In our deployment process it is crucial that we are informed, when a deployment fails. The deployment is rolling, but an information through slack would be nice anyway. Would it be possible through lifecycles or what other possibilities do exist?

Answer (score 0):

The deployment status is logging out as events logs from OpenShift usually.
Do you use OpenShift logging component EFK stack ? Then additionally consider to install [EventRouter](https://github.com/openshift/eventrouter/tree/fec0a81d9966c93bd544d5407be79001034e0c25#eventrouter), it collects OpenShift events logs as eventrouter pod's logs.
You can pick up the deployment event messages from the logs and trigger the alert by custom script or monitoring system's log tailing feature and so on.

Refer [Specifying Logging Ansible Variables](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/aggregate_logging.html#aggregate-logging-ansible-variables)
 for ansible variable details.

```
openshift_logging_install_eventrouter
openshift_logging_eventrouter_nodeselector
openshift_logging_eventrouter_namespace
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass customParams to the deployment process and do a curl if openshift-deploy fails.

```
"strategy": {
  "type": "Rolling",
  "timeoutSeconds": 180,
  "customParams": {
    "command": [
      "/bin/sh",
      "-c",
      "set -e && if ! openshift-deploy; then curl -i -X POST -d '{\"text\": \"Deployment of ${application} failed!\"}' ${webhook} && exit 1; else echo \"Deployment complete\"; fi"
    ]
}
```